# `button.click` just shows the click function but doesn’t execute the click

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to programmatically click on a button from the console in Google Chrome. I have tried many different ways, but nothing works.

The HTML looks like this:

```html
<button class="btn-standard call-to-action">Suchen</button>
```

I can get the right button, e.g. with `getElementsByTagName`:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[20]
// => <button class=​"btn-standard call-to-action">​Suchen​</button>​
```

But when I try to execute a click, it looks like this and nothing happens; the button is not clicked:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[20].click
// => ƒ click() { [native code] }
```

How can I execute a click on that button?

Comment: You’r not executing any click. You’re just getting the [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method. Methods are called with `()`.

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[20].click()` instead

Answer (score 5):

Use `.click()` instead of `.click`.

Comment: I tried this too. If I execute it, it says undefined.

Comment: @peldroid Try giving the button an `id` attribute and use `document.getElementsById('{button id}')`. And create a function within your javascript for your click action. And then can use `onclick={javascript function name}`. It will look like `button class="btn-standard call-to-action" onclick="{JavaScript function}()">Suchen</button>` Or you can use JQuery and make a function for everytime you click the button such as `$(document).on('click','{button id}', function(){...});`